# Find the line integral of $x^2+y^2$ over the polar curve $r=e^{\theta}$

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, line-integrals

Find the line integral of $x^2+y^2$ over the polar curve $r=e^{\theta}$

Not really sure on how to find the curve on terms of a parameter in order to evaluate the integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, so the integral you're trying to find is $\int r^2\, ds$, where $ds$ is the arc-length form $$ds = \sqrt{r^2 + \left( \frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2}\, d\theta$$
In this case $r = \frac{dr}{d\theta} = e^{\theta}$, so plugging in gives $$\int r^2 ds = \int (e^\theta)^2 \sqrt{2 (e^\theta)^2}\, d\theta = \int \sqrt{2} e^{3\theta}\, d\theta. $$

Answer (score 0):

You can parameterize your curve $c$ by the polar angle theta as $$c(\theta) = (x(\theta),y(\theta)) = (r(\theta)\cos\theta, r(\theta)\sin\theta) = (e^\theta\cos\theta, e^\theta\sin\theta)$$

so $\dot{c}(\theta) = e^\theta(\cos\theta-\sin\theta, \sin\theta+\cos\theta)$ and $\|\dot{c}(\theta)\| = \sqrt2e^\theta$.

We get
$$\int_c (x^2+y^2)\,ds = \int_c (x^2+y^2)\,ds = \int r(c(\theta))^2\|\dot{c}(\theta)\|\,d\theta = \sqrt2\int e^{3\theta}\,d\theta$$